# Is it possible to list values of a function with 2 variables in python? If so how?

Tags: python-2.7, list

I've figured out how to list the values of a function with one variable. For that I just do the following:

```
def f(x): 
    return x*x
mylist = [f(x) for x in range(4)]
```

That's an example where it returns the first 4 values of integers of x squared, so 0, 1, 4, and 9. 
However, when I try to do something like

```
def f(x, y): 
    return x*x-y*y
```

I don't know how to format it, if possible here. 
Thanks in advance

Edit: Someone marked this as a duplicate, but the alternative has to do with how to combine different parts of a list into 1, when I'm asking for how to list the values of a multi variable function using the format said above.

Comment: To format a multi-line block of code, select it and click the `{}` button in the editor, or precede it with four-space indents.

Comment: BTW, with Python, indentation is crucial -- so we ask that you not just provide formatting, but *ensure that the indentation is correct as-displayed*.

Comment: I do not really get what values `x` and `y` should take?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem x and y can take any values, I just need to see how it's done so I could do it in multiple different equations